# MSER on Videotracking

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, mser

I've a time problem. I have programmed a qt Gui for imageprocessing. For this case it would be relevant to implement blobdectetors for videoprocessing and object tracking. Principally it looks good. It uses with GUI behind processing, grabbing, mser operation and  displaying just 0.07 to 0.08 seconds which could be used for a nice framerate over 10 fps.

For that purposes i user Qt 4 - C++, on Suse 12.3. OpenCV 2.4.3 and a laptop webcam. My problem is, that after a short while my program's hanging.

Looking at my system monitor i am seeing that CPU-Power has reached 100 % and a single run uses hard ressources of cpu uses processor for long time (without GUI). I don't understand what is going wrong. Has anybody experiences with that?

TY in advance!

Some Code snippets:
MSER Initialisation about GUI:

```
MSER FtMSERVid( MSERDelta, MSERMinArea, MSERMaxArea,MSERMaxVariation ,MSERMinDiversity);
```

videoprocessing function

```
double startTime = clock();
camDev.read(vidImg);
if(vidImg.empty() == true)
{
    newLineInText(tr("No data from device"));
    timer->stop();
    ui->pbPlay->setText(tr(">"));
    return;
}

MSERPointsVid.clear();
if(vidImg.channels() > 1)
    cvtColor(vidImg, vidImg,CV_BGR2GRAY);
FtMSERVid(vidImg, MSERPointsVid);

Mat showMat = vidImg.clone();
if(showMat.channels() > 1)
{
    cvtColor(showMat,showMat,CV_BGR2RGB);
    qImg = QImage((uchar*)showMat.data,showMat.cols,showMat.rows,showMat.step,QImage::Format_RGB888);
 }
else if(showMat.channels() == 1)
    qImg =   QImage((uchar*)showMat.data,showMat.cols,showMat.rows,showMat.step,QImage::Format_Indexed8);
ui->lblOrig->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(qImg));
double endTime = clock();
double timeDuration = (endTime - startTime)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

if(numVid%10 == 0)
{
   framesPS = int(1/timeDuration) - 1;
   if(framesPS > 1)
       framesPS = 1;
   FPSChanged(framesPS);
   numVid = 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you use some profiling tool (even the basic top in command line) to get the name of the process / or the function that uses all your CPU? Also, what you could try would be to separate image processing tasks (MSER, etc.) from the main thread and put them in a separate one, so that your GUI won't block at least.

Comment: Thanks for your hint sansuiso,

i have installed valgrind and profiled the program. The analysis result is that what i expected. If i understood it right then valgrind just checked the memory. The called functions don't use these large amount. Principally it is just an amount  of using CPU Power while using MSER function. The initialization uses 12% but this was the largest amount. Is there a mistake?

thanks!

PS: i don't use threading stuff. Or do i? I am not really sure.

Comment: You can use valgrind to test for memory allc/dealloc that may slow you down, or possible errors in MSER code (compile OpenCV with debug option). Besides valgrind, cachegrind can help you detect some performance bottleneck issues. Gcc also has some profiling options too. As for the threading thing, it's usually a good practice to off load compute intensive tasks into separate threads. You can try QThread for this, right?

Comment: Yes i can but i have used. I've tried threading on the simple way

    
    std::thread MSERThread(FtMSERVid,ref(vidImgProc),ref(MSERPointsVid));
        MSERThread.join();

Comment: Another thing worth investigating: do you see the same phenomenon whithout GUI, when using a command line program to do the tracking? And maybe try replacing MSER by something else to see if it is some bug linked to MSER.

Comment: Thank you for your hint. I had the same idea this morning. There it works really fine.  I showed the called duration times that i have found out in the first post and everything worked fine. 

The valgrind program showed me a large amount of costs in the GUI main function, but not in the GUI itself, it has made the costs in the exec function of QApplication. I am now thinking again about the thread stuff. I am not sure which thread fuctionality (boost, Qt,...) i should use.

Answer (score 1):

your hints have helped me to solve a problem. MSER is creating a lot data and i have programmed for displaying that a secondly update into a table, which works independently. So far no problem but it is to much for the table to display all the Points.So it was provided just to fill the hullpoints in the table. I have changed the according vector and then it runs like nothing else.

That i have found out because of your hint to valgrind. I have never needed this before. The threading hints have let me learned much about threading. Thank you for that.

Ingeborg